Equivalent to siunitx for cgs units?
I have always used the siunitx package to write quantities with units, for example:
\begin{gather*}
x = \SI{2.5}{\meter} \\
q = \SI{1.6e-19}{\coulomb} \\
m = \SI{5.29}{\kilo\gram} \\
\end{gather*}

However, in many branches of physics such as astrophysics, the CGS unit system is preferred. In addition, astrophysics uses many unique units such as parsec, AU, light years, etc which aren't built in with siunitx. Is there an equivalent package to siunitx which provides units for CGS and astrophysics? I know I can define custom units with siunitx, but I wanted to know if there is a more robust package for people who use the CGS system and astrophysics.

In theory there is https://ctan.org/pkg/physunits , however I would use siunitx and just define the units you need.

As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, there's no real issue in using siunitx. -the only 'SI' is what's pre-defined and the idea of prefix manipulation, everything else is just 'some number + some unit text'.

For example: How to typeset imperial/US customary units, especially in combination with SI/metric units
